# How to delete an app without deleting app data?

Tags: applications, delete

I'm on an Android and my device is a Huawei. I got this device a few months ago and I don't want to root my device because I don't trust myself.

Is there a way to delete an app without deleting app data?

If possible, I don't want to use ADB because I don't know any good apps and my computer is in a bad state and I just don't want to use it. Even if it's a hard or complicated way, I might do it. I do have other devices that might help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fully backup non-rooted devices?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/how-to-fully-backup-non-rooted-devices)

Comment: Don't think it's possible, especially without root. When an app is uninstalled all its folders are automatically deleted unless it explicitly creates a folder in your internal storage (which is why many apps do).

Comment: @SSS for "user apps" it is easily possible, see my answer below. For pre-installed apps you need root, and a more complicated approach.

Comment: @lzzy is there any good abd app? how do I open abd

Comment: @gaurav patil and how am I supposed to acess root files without rooting?

Comment: I feel there's a missing context that might give alternative solutions: is there a reason why you want to uninstall the app but still keep the app's data?

Comment: https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are talking about apps you've installed yourself (and not about pre-installed apps), you can utilise [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) for this. You need to know the app's package name first (the part shown in the Play Store URL in the `id=` parameter, or at F-Droid following the `/package/` in the URL). Then, with your device connected:

```
adb uninstall -k <app.package.name>
```

replacing `<app.package.name>` by the app's package name. The `-k` parameter is telling `uninstall` to *keep* the app's data. So when you next install the app, the data is already there and will be used.